# (Java).getRGB(): does changing image size affect the speed of getRGB() if the scan area is the same?

Tags: java, image, memory, graphics, rgb

Let me explain: Imagine I had an image of size 500x500, and I wanted to scan the RGB values of a rectangle that is 100x150 inside this image. If the image were bigger, say 1000x1000 and the rectangle area is still the same, would java (or whatever) have to go through every point of the image so it can then scan the rectangle... which would mean more work, right? Or is the image size trivial in this case

Ultimately, I just want to know if it would be a better idea to trim the image to my rectangle and then scan it, instead of taking the whole image and scanning just a part of it.

Let me know if I need to make it clearer.
Also my knowledge of graphics and stuff is not so impressive so excuse me if I offended u with my question :P

Comment: This is an optimization problem, and normally you optimize for speed (time), or size (memory), or try to balance. IO is normally the slowest operation so you try to keep file size small. 
But optimization is not always necessary, so you should start simple and optimize when needed.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful, since I want to optimize more for speed rather than memory I stumbled upon ImageMagick, going to try it out!

Comment: why do you want to learn new junk? the image will be read whole when it is loaded; then the getRGB will get only the rectangle you need- I dont think perplexing yourself with j-nonsense will help

Comment: Well in this case getRGB() is worse than junk, it is incredibly slow and that wont do. I gotta admit that JMagick is complete chaos, but I need to look for other options